# Jmeter variable value update based on time

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

Problem statement:
I have a variable that needs to be updated every 4 hours based on time in JMeter with out stopping the test, any logic suggestions

any alternative other than this: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-change-jmeters-load-during-runtime

Comment: Is it a variable or a JMeter property that you want to update? What is the variable/property you want to update and what is the purpose (use case) ?

Comment: it is a variable. I want to update it every 4 hours irrespective of the iteration. purpose is data set changes every 4 hours in system. so in 4 hours intervals we are trying to pass fresh data to application.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with a little bit of [Groovy scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/), the following code placed in any of [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) will update the `myVariable` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) name with the number of current [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration each 4 hours:

```
def lastUpdateTime = displayName = vars.get('lastUpdateTime') ?: vars.get('START.MS')

def currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

if ((currentTime - (lastUpdateTime as long)) > 14400000) {
    vars.put('myVariable', 'myValue_' + vars.getIteration())
    vars.put('lastUpdateTime', currentTime as String)
}
```

Comment: is there a way to pass values using csvread function at vars.getIteration(), I tried doing it and for every iteration the csv is being called even when the case is not true code: `def lastUpdateTime = displayName = vars.get('lastUpdateTime') ?: vars.get('START.MS') def currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() if ((currentTime - (lastUpdateTime as long)) > 10000) { vars.put('myVariable', 'myValue_' + ${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}) vars.put('lastUpdateTime', currentTime as String) }`

Answer (score 0):

Current solution:
we have added a jsr223 sampler with the following code:

```
StartTime = 1637666165643;
int CsvNo;
def CurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
TimeDiff = (CurrentTime - (StartTime as long));
log.info("Time Difference = "+TimeDiff);
CsvNo = TimeDiff/14400000 + 1;
log.info("Csv File No = "+CsvNo);
String MasterCSVFile1 = '<path to csv>test'+CsvNo;
log.info(''+MasterCSVFile1);
vars.put('Path_Final',''+MasterCSVFile1);
vars.put('myVariable','${__CSVRead(${Path_Final}.csv,0)}${__CSVRead(${Path_Final}.csv,next)}')
```

Comment: this code checks on each iteration, if there is code that triggers every four hours that would be helpful..  if we keep csv read function inside a if controller that loops every four hours the csv file is looping on iteration basis only